# animated gif vs video vs canvas - for speed & file size

Tags: performance, video, html5-canvas, html5-video, animated-gif

Assuming a simple product demo e.g. the one found on http://www.sublimetext.com/

i.e. something this isn't traditional high res video and could be reasonable accomplished with:

- animated gif
- video (can be embedded youtube, custom html5 player, whatever is most competitive)
- canvas

The question is, which performs better for the user? Both in terms of:

1. The size of the files the user must be downloaded to view the 'product demo'
2. The requirements in terms of processing power to display the 'product demo'

If you feel that there's a superior technology to accomplish this or another metric to judge its usefulness, let me know and I'll adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know it's already answered, but as you specifically referred to the Sublime Text animation I assume you're wanting to create something similar?

If that's the case then here is a post explaining how it was created by the Sublime Text author, himself:

- http://www.sublimetext.com/~jps/animated_gifs_the_hard_way.html

The interesting part of the article is how he reduces the file size - which I believe is your question.

Comment: here's the animation encored that he made, hosted on github — it seems to be in active development: https://github.com/sublimehq/anim_encoder

Answer (score 3):

With a simple animation such as the one at the link you're referring to, with a very low frame rate, a simple animated-PNG of animated GIF will probably be the best solution.

However, you need to consider band-width factor in this. If the final size of the GIF or the PNG is large then probably a buffered video is probably better.

This is because the whole gif/png file needs to be downloaded before it shows (I am not sure how interleaved PNGs works when they contain animation though).

A video may be larger in file size, but as it is typically buffered you will be able to show the animation almost right away.

Using external hosts such as YouTube or others can be beneficial to your site as well as the band-width is drawn from those site and not from your server (in case you use a provider that limits or charge for this in various ways).

For more information on animated PNGs or APNG (as this is not so well-known):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG

The canvas in this is only a displaying device and not really necessary (an image container does the same job and can also animate the GIF/PNG whereas a canvas cannot).

If you use a lot of vectors then canvas can be considered.

CSS3 animation is also an option for things such as presentation slides.

Comment: So, animated PNGs aren't supported on IE, Safari, or Chrome?